# Failed to start quarkus: Failed to load steps from class io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, quarkus

I try to run `compile quarkus:dev` with my own `cloud` profile, but just found this error and cannot go to next step. I use Quarkus 1.9.2.Final

```
2020-12-14 16:47:17,515 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load steps from class io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:75)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:360)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:52)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:129)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:144)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load steps from class io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:214)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:98)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:250)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No root found for class io.quarkus.runtime.logging.LogBuildTimeConfig
    at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader$ReadResult.requireRootObjectForClass(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:754)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:739)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:212)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure all your versions are aligned? Because it typically looks like a version alignment issue.

Check that all your Quarkus dependencies use the same version, the Quarkus Maven plugin included.

Comment: Checked before and all Quarkus versions for dependencies are valid and the same.

Comment: Even the Quarkus Maven plugin?

Comment: If you can get together a reproducer, open an issue in our tracker with it attached. I’ll have a look. 

Just to be on the safe side, if you have upgraded from a previous version, be sure you do a clean. Stating the obvious but it looks very odd. 

Anyway, get me a reproducer and I’ll check what’s going on.

Comment: I faced the same issue and in my case the `quarkus-maven-plugin` in my pom was missing the `version` coordinate which means maven was picking up the latest. Solved after aligning the `quarkus-maven-plugin` version